# GoogleMaps does not show on inactive tab (Yii2)

Tags: google-maps, tabs, yii2

I'm using Kartik [tabs-x](http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x#w64-tab0) and [yii2-google-maps-marker](https://yiigist.com/package/yii2mod/yii2-google-maps-markers#?tab=readme).

If the Tab 2 is set active, googleMap shows correctly.

[image]

But, If I set the Tab 1 (not 2) to active, googleMap shows incorrectly.

[image]

This is Tab-x in view.

```
<?php
    $datsan_tab_items = [
        [
            'label'=>'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>'.Yii::t('app', ' Tab 1'),
            'content'=> $this->render('_calendar_dat_san',['ids_sanCon' => $ids_sanCon,
                            'modelSanCon' => $modelSanCon,
                            'modelSanChu' => $modelSanChu
                        ]),
            'active'=>false
        ],
        [
            'label'=>'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>'.Yii::t('app', ' Tab 2'),
            'content'=> $this->render('_map',['dc' => $dc, 'modelSanChu' => $modelSanChu]),
            'active'=>true,
        ],
        [
            'label'=>'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>'.Yii::t('app', ' Tab 3'),
            'content'=> $this->render('_bang_gia',[
                        'modelSanCon' => $modelSanCon,
                        'modelSanChu' => $modelSanChu
                    ]),
            'active'=>false
        ],
    ];
    // Tab Chuyen doi giua Login/Register
    echo TabsX::widget([
        'items'=>$datsan_tab_items,
        'position'=>TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
        'bordered'=>true,
        'encodeLabels'=>false
    ]);
    ?>
```

This is map view.

```
<div class="datsan-index-thong-tin-ban-do" id="datsan-index-thong-tin-ban-do">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><?= Yii::t('app', ' Bản Đồ') ?></div> <?php
        echo GoogleMaps::widget([
            'userLocations' => [
                [
                    'location' => [
                        'address' => $dc,
                        'country' => $modelSanChu->dc_quocGia,
                    ],
                    'htmlContent' => $modelSanChu->ten
                ],
            ],
            'wrapperHeight' => '350px',
            'googleMapsUrlOptions' => [
                'key' => Yii::$app->params['GOOGLE_API_KEY'],
            ]
        ]);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If google maps is inside `div` that has `display:none` style, or it's parent, or it's parent's parent (any predecessor) has `display:none` style, the map view won't initialise correctly. But no worries, there is an easy fix, you just have to trigger `resize` event on map. So using javascript, AFTER you switch to a desired tab (must be after, so google maps div is already visible!) just  call:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(yii.googleMapManager.map, "resize");
```

It seems you work with `TabX`, so probably you know how to best determine when tab was clicked. But in case you don't, maybe give `pluginEvents` attribute a try. According to [docs](http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x#w64-tab0) you should be able to do this:

```
echo TabsX::widget([
    'items'=>$datsan_tab_items,
    'position'=>TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
    'bordered'=>true,
    'encodeLabels'=>false,
    'pluginEvents' = [
          "tabsX.click" => "function() { 
                 setTimeout(function() {
                     google.maps.event.trigger(yii.googleMapManager.map, 'resize');
                 }, 200);
           }"
     ]
]);
```

Sam updated: Changed timeout from 10 to 200.

Comment: Thanks Matej P. But it did not work. I tried using google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); instead but it did not work too. I don't know the reason. Could you give any advice to debug ?

Comment: I add a button on _map.php: <?= \yii\helpers\Html::button('Resize', ['onclick' => 'google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize);' ]) ?> to test. But it did work.

Comment: Since you use the `yii2-google-maps-marker` library, the `map` variable doesn't exist in your context. Instead you should use `yii.googleMapManager.map`. 
Try to console.log() the yii.googleMapManager object like this when clicking the resize button: `<?= \yii\helpers\Html::button('Resize', ['onclick' => 'console.log(yii.googleMapManager); google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");' ]) ?>` and let me know what it prints into browser console. Maybe also try to console.log(google); there to check if library is available. Do you have the project available on some url? I can try to help you debug.

Comment: I have just added the debug code as you suggested and then deployed to heroku. Could you please take a look at  http://datsan.herokuapp.com/datsan/index?id_sanChu=31

Comment: Just add this exact code to resize button: `<?= \yii\helpers\Html::button('Resize', ['onclick' => 'google.maps.event.trigger(yii.googleMapManager.map, "resize");' ]) ?>` and it should work. It works for me on the link you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much matej. It works! 
So, your above answer is correct, I just changed timeout from 10 to 1000 and it works. You saved my time. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Matej. I want to ask one more question. When I switch to the Map tab, the map content shows incorrectly the position where I want to point out. The target position is shifted into the left corner of map. How do fix this?

Comment: Do you mean that the marker is not centered to the middle of the map? In that case try to call `yii.googleMapManager.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(YOUR_LATITUDE, YOUR_LONGITUDE));` right after the resize. If it's something else please update your question with a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I do. But I'm using the address of location to get the location on map via a extension, so I don't know LATITUDE and LONGTITUDE of the location.

Comment: Then try `if(yii.googleMapManager.markers.length) yii.googleMapManager.map.setCenter(yii.googleMapManager.markers[0].getPosition())` . This should center the map to the position of first marker on map (if there is one)

Comment: Thanks Matej. It seems that `yii.googleMapManager.map.setCenter(yii.googleMapManager.markers[0].getPosition()‌​)` did not work correctly.  I tried `alert(yii.googleMapManager.markers[0].getPosition()‌);`, but this did not work. I also tried ` yii.googleMapManager.map.setCenter(16.074652,108.231775);`, this did not work too.